# probability of showing different numbers two times

Tags: probability

> Three different dice are rolled $3$ times. The probability that they shows different number only two times, is

what i try

probability of showing one number in first dice is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{6}$

probability of showing different number in second dice is $\displaystyle \frac{5}{6}$

and probability of showing different number in third  dice is $\displaystyle \frac{4}{6}$

How do i solve it Help me please

Comment: Are there nine rolls in all, that is, are each of the three dice rolled three times?

Comment: Yes N. F. Tausung each of the three dice rolled $3$ times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one roll of each dice, the probability to get different numbers, calling this event $E$, is given by counting every possible outcomes.
We have $6^3$ possible outcomes. Among those, to have three different numbers, you have 6 choices for the first dice, 5 for the second one, and 4 for the third one. I don't care about the order for both cases (this will add a factor 6 to both the numerator and the denominator). 
Overall, the probability to obtain different numbers is

$$ 6*5*4/6^3 = 20/36 = 5/9. $$

Finally, you repeat the same experience three times and you want exactly two successes. The probability of one success if $5/9$ so a straightforward application of the binomial law gives you:
$$3*(5/9)^2*(4/9),$$
which is the desired probabilities.